# Show convergence of a serie with unknown exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For $\sum a_n$ convergent and also $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: $a_n\geq0$, show that:
>   $$ \sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\alpha}$$ converges for $\alpha> \frac{1}{2}$.

My idea was to use the Direct comparison test, I'm pretty sure that's the way to prove it, and to find a bigger series that also converges, but I haven't been able to find one appropriate series.

It would be very helpful if you could give me a hint on how this bigger series. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality), we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\alpha}=\sum_{n=1}^N \sqrt{a_n}\cdot\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\right)^{1/2}\cdot \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}\right)^{1/2}.$$
Can you take it from here?